# Strange __EVENTTARGET behavior, possible bug?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, postback

Herro. I have a strange problem that I am dealing with that involves two buttons, an HTML (client-side "Export to Excel") and an ASP (server-side "Go") button:

[image]

Here is the html for the two buttons:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnGo" runat="server" Text="Go" OnClick="btnGoClick" Width="35px" />
<input id="btnExport" type="button" value="Export to Excel" disabled="disabled" onclick="btnExClick(this)" onmouseover="return doHover(this)" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='';" style="width: 125px" />
```

Basically the user selects in the drop down, what loans to load, and clicks "Go", which queries the database and loads the data grid. When a datagrid is loaded the "Export to Excel" button becomes enabled and will turn to and from the color green when the user hovers the mouse over and off. When clicked, it fires and event that just calls `__doPostBack(btnEx.id, '');`

**Edit Per ShadowWizard's Request:** Here is my btnExClick():

```
function btnExClick(btn)
{
    document.forms[0].target = "_blank";  //newly added line from shadowwizard
    __doPostBack(btn.id, '');
}
```

In my code-behind, I have the following code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        .....

        if (Request.Form["__EVENTTARGET"] == "btnExport")
        {
            this.ExportExcel();
        }
    }

    protected void ExportExcel()
    {
        Response.Clear();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Optoma Loaner Report.xls");
        Response.Charset = "";
        this.EnableViewState = false;

        System.IO.StringWriter sw = new System.IO.StringWriter();
        System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htw = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(sw);

        dgResults.RenderControl(htw);

        Response.Write(sw.ToString());
        Response.End();
    }
```

This all works fine, and I get a nice looking Excel sheet. The only problem is after I "Export to Excel", my "Go" button no longer works. It just performs a "postback" with an __EVENTTARGET still = "btnExport", so it attempts to export to excel again.. It doesn't even go to its server-side onclick event handler! Does anyone know why this is happening?

I'm assuming it has something to do with the way I export my datagrid to an excel sheet, because when I comment out `this.ExportExcel();`, it continues to work fine (although the "Export to Excel" button goes back to being disabled after I click it, and I'm not sure why. It doesn't normally do that).

Comment: "although the "Export to Excel" button goes back to being disabled after I click it, and I'm not sure why. It doesn't normally do that" I guess that is normal behavior for html controls to go back to default state on postbacks.. so for it to not do that (like it would when ExportExcel() is uncommented) is saying something is wrong...

Comment: have you resolved the problem or you just switched to using ASP button instead of input control?

Answer (score 3):

I had this exact issue.

The fix is to set `UseSubmitBehavior="false"` on your `btnGo` button.

`UseSubmitBehavior="false"` causes the button to use .NET's postback methodology which will set `__EVENTTARGET` to "`btnGo`" when the button is clicked.  Without it, the button is using the browser's default methodology for submit buttons which leaves `__EVENTTARGET` unchanged and therefore resubmits the previous value of "`btnExport`".

Comment: Hi Shredder. Did this fix the problem?

Answer (score 1):

This probably happens because you Clear the response and Ending it.. I would try to open the Excel in new browser window by changing the form target before submitting the form.

How to do that? By adding such line to `btnExClick` function:

```
document.forms[0].target = "_blank";
```

Hopefully this will cause the Excel to open in new window and leave the original window intact.

Comment: "This probably happens because you Clear the response and Ending it" probably true, but that didn't fix it. It opens a new browser window and excel sheet, then they both close when I "exit" the excel sheet, and my "Go" button now does the same

Comment: When I comment out Response.clear() and/or Response.end() I get the whole webpage in my excel sheet, and it does not solve anything :(

Comment: @Nick that's weird.. please post the code for `btnExClick` function and we'll see what might cause this.

Comment: Ok, I edited it into my OP. it only does what i said it does, nothing more, other than what you suggested.

Comment: @Nick I'm stumped.. what about AJAX? Is this a valid option?

Answer (score 0):

Usually, you tie the excel generator to a generic handler (.ashx file).  The handlers entire purpose is to take a couple parameters and emit the excel file.

In your page code you just tie the button click to pull up the .ashx file.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm trying this out, and I can't think of a way to pass my StringWriter object to this ASHX file, except through query string.. which seems sloppy, but I suppose I will try next. I just tried to pass through Session, but I can't retrieve the Session variable in the ASHX file. I get an "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" exception

Comment: I can't pass it thru queryString either. I get an error saying queryString cannot contain new line characters XD maybe I will put a bounty on this

Comment: Okay, so I implemented System.Web.SessionState.IReadOnlySessionState in my ASHX file and was able to read my session variable. And it worked! Except that it didn't solve my problem in slightest bit! I even tried adding another random asp:button that just changes a label's text when clicked. Once my Excel sheet gets created, all buttons on the page just postback with an __EVENTTARGET of "btnExport"!! ><

Answer (score 0):

Not getting too many responses, maybe I can spark some up. I think the reason this might be happening is because the response isn't being returned to the "browser", so to speak, but to an excel sheet. I think that's why I'm not seeing my html controls go back to default state like they normally should on a postback. So maybe when I try to do another postback its still feeding it the same postback as before.. but how could I prevent that..


Well, the whole reason I use an html button is to do a fancy color change. If I use an ASP:Button onclick handler to do my export, it works fine and I get no problems. I'm not sure where the problem lies, between using an html button and __doPostBack() and an asp button onclick event to do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue--an ASP button to get data and an html button to export it to Excel.  My solution was to call a JavaScript from the ASP button "OnClientClick" to clear __EVENTTARGET value:

```
OnClientClick="clearEVENTTARGET(); return true;"

function clearEVENTTARGET() {
        this.<form name here>.__EVENTTARGET.value = '';
    };
```